# The closure of the set of nondegenerate plane conics that tangent to two fixed lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

Consider a (general) conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ over the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$,
\begin{equation}
Q : aX^2+2bXY+cY^2+2dXZ+2eYZ+fZ^2=0.
\end{equation}
Then we have known that the space of all conics is parametrized by $\mathbb{P}^5$.

Now, I wonder that what is the closure of the Zariski open set that consists of nondegenerate (nonsingular) conics in $\mathbb{P}^3$, that the space of conics tangent to given two projective lines.

At the first glance, I guess the closure is a union of two surfaces isomorphic to
$\mathbb{P}^2$ and a quadric $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$.

For example, suppose that $Q$ is tangent to two lines $f_1:(X=0) $ and $f_2:(Y=0) $. Then
\begin{equation}
Q|_{f_1}: cY^2+2eYZ+fZ^2=0
\end{equation}
and then we must have $e^2-cf=0$, while
\begin{equation}
Q|_{f_2}: aX^2+2dXZ+fZ^2=0
\end{equation}
gives $d^2-af=0$.

After we subsituate this consqeuences, we have a set of conics that 1-1 correspondence to a space $\mathbb{P}^3$ that of the forms
\begin{equation}
Q' : aX^2+2bXY+cY^2+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{f}XZ+2\sqrt{c}\sqrt{f}YZ+fZ^2=0.
\end{equation}

Now, Q is degenerate (singular) conic if and only if the determinant of 3x3 matrix
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & \sqrt{a}\sqrt{f}\\
 b & c & \sqrt{c}\sqrt{f}\\
 \sqrt{a}\sqrt{f} & \sqrt{c}\sqrt{f} & f
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
is $0$.

1. $(f=0)$
   In this case, we always have the determinant $0$, so the variants $b, a, c$ are all free (That is, it fulfills $\mathbb{P}^2$. Furthermore, $Q':aX^2+2bXY+cY^2=0$ and it is either line pair, or double line that pass through $f_1\cap f_2$.

2. $(f\neq 0)$
   Then the determinant is $f(b-\sqrt{a}\sqrt{c})$, and the zero set of this formular is a quadric $b-\sqrt{a}\sqrt{c}=0$ in the underlying space $\mathbb{P}^3$. Furthermore, $Q':(\sqrt{a}X+\sqrt{C}Y+\sqrt{f}Z)^2=0$ are double lines meet $f_1$ and $f_2$ separately, namely, $(0:\sqrt{f}:\sqrt{c})$ and $(\sqrt{f}:0:\sqrt{a})$.

**Question :**

1. Is there any misunderstanding to my claim?
2. Is it true for the general case (for the given any two lines)?

Thank you!

Comment: A comic tangent to two lines is dual to a conic incident with two points. For non-degenerate conics you can translate between primal and dual using the inverse of the matrix representation. Also the specific choice of lines shouldn't matter; any two distinct lines are projectively equivalent to any other two.

Comment: A comic typo... :)

Comment: Thank you @MvG :) So as I understand, the choice of the two tangent lines doesn't matter in the case. Is there any idea or comment about the geometry of the closure?